# Carregar resposta para outra página

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Tenho uma lista de projetos cadastrados e o usuário pode selecionar um deles e clicar em avançar para descrever mais detalhes na outra página. Gostaria de que, ao ser pressionado o botão de avançar, além de ser enviado dois dados para uma outra tabela e vá para a outra página, o dado "id_prestacao" fique como se fosse uma sessão, já que no outro formulário seguinte ele será enviado automaticamente junto com os outros dados. As duas partes relacionadas estão abaixo. Outro problema é que quando eu não tinha feito ainda essa parte do PHP de cima, o usuário conseguia selecionar normalmente os projetos que vinham da outra tabela, mas depois que fiz isso não está aparecendo nenhuma informação nas options. Como posso prosseguir?

```
<?php
session_start();
include('classes/db_connect.php');
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id_projeto, nome_projeto FROM projetos");

if (isset($_POST['avancar']))
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM prestacoes";
    $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
    $nomeproj = $_POST['nomeProjeto'];
    $insert="INSERT INTO prestacoes(
      id_user,
      nome_projeto)
    VALUES(
      '$id_user',
      '$nomeproj')";
?>
```

```
<body>

    <form action="/user/registrarDespesas.php" method="POST" enctype ="multipart/form-data" name="prestacao">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="element">
        <div class="logo">
                <img src="confidencial"/ width="150px">
                
                </div> 
        
        <p><select name="nomeProjeto" id="nova" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Projeto</option>
        <?php while($prod = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $prod['id_projeto']?>"><?php echo $prod['nome_projeto'] ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select></p>
        
        <p><button name ="avancar" action="/user/registrarDespesas.php" class="btn btn-grey">avançar</button></p> <br>
        <p><a class="link" id="fin" href="/user/selecionarPrest.php" style="text-decoration:none;">retornar</a></p>

        </div>


    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Onde está o SELECT pra realizar o while da parte de baixo da sua pergunta. Porque na parte de cima tem dois  SELECT?

Comment: O while debaixo está pegando o primeiro SELECT que aparece no código, pelo mysqli_query
Até o momento consegui ajustar pra ser enviado o nome do projeto para a outra sessão, mas ainda não consegui passar o id da prestação (auto incrementado) para ela.

Comment: if(mysqli_query($connect,$insert)){
    $prestacao = "SELECT id_prestacao FROM prestacoes WHERE id_user = $id_user";
    $_SESSION['prestacao'] = $prestacao;
    $_SESSION['nomeproj'] = $nomeproj;
    header('Location: /user/registrarDespesas.php');
    }
    else {
    echo "Erro! Contate um dos adiministradores.";
    }
}
?>
Depois de inserir essa parte do código, você saberia me dizer o porquê do $_SESSION['id_prestacao'] estar sendo levado como nulo pra outra página? (Ele é do tipo auto incrementado na tabela)

Comment: Tá meio confuso, não seria melhor postar em cada bloco os códigos referentes a cada página?

Comment: Onde que tá esse $_SESSION['id_prestacao'] na sua pergunta?

Comment: ao invés de $_SESSION['prestacao'] = $prestacao; não deveria ser $_SESSION['id_prestacao']  = $prestacao;

Answer (score 0):

Você nao poderia usar o input do type="hidden"

```html
<?php
    <input type="hidden" name="id_prestcao" value=<?=$id_prestacao?> >
    
?>
```

Comment: Já consegui resolver isto Samuel, na verdade utilizei o método readonly. O motivo de eu não usar o hidden é porque seria uma saída na interface pro usuário ver qual projeto ele selecionou.